# og:type ARTICLE not being parsed In Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I have defined and created a new object-action,i.e., READ-ARTICLE

However, the Facebook debug tool and the unix terminal (CURL) both show an error saying that the og:type is WEBSITE. I have cross checked and it is indeed ARTICLE. moreover, the term website does not appear on the entire web page.

this is my head tag

```
     <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# codereplugd: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/codereplugd#">
    <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="MY_APP_ID" /> 
    <meta property="og:type"        content="article" /> 
    <meta property="og:url"         content="http://www.codereplugd.com" /> 
    <meta property="og:title"       content="CodeReplugd" /> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="Share.Learn.Discover" /> 
    <meta property="og:image"       content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" />
```

the actual source contains my app ID..i also tried replacing the type to "namespace:article", where namespace had my actual namespace

Comment: Have you tried this tool — https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ ?
I had the same problem and could fix it in "real" Facebook debugger as it gives exact information about what's wrong.